# Loop Unrolling Multi Dimesional Array

Tags: c, performance, optimization, loop-unrolling

I recently tried unrolling the inner i and j loops within this multi-dimensional array, but the filter->get(i,j) always messes up the texture of the image. Can anyone assist me with unrolling the i and j loop? Thanks.

My attempt:

```
double
applyFilter(struct Filter *filter, cs1300bmp *input, cs1300bmp *output)
{

     long long cycStart, cycStop;

     cycStart = rdtscll();

    output -> width = input -> width;
    output -> height = input -> height;
int a = filter -> getDivisor();
int n = filter -> getSize();
for (int plane = 0; plane < 3; plane++){
    for(int row = 1; row < (input -> height) - 1 ; row = row + 1) {
        for(int col = 1; col < (input -> width) - 1; col = col + 1) {
            int value = 0;
            int val1, val2;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i+=2) {
                    val1 = val1 + input -> color[plane][row + i - 1][col + j - 1]
                    * filter -> get(i, j);
                    val2 = val2 + input -> color[plane][row + i][col + j -1] * filter->get(i+1,j);
                }
            }
            value = (val1 + val2) / a;
            if ( value  < 0 ) { value = 0; }
            if ( value  > 255 ) { value = 255; }
            output -> color[plane][row][col] = value;
        }

    }
}

 cycStop = rdtscll();
 double diff = cycStop - cycStart;
 double diffPerPixel = diff / (output -> width * output -> height);
 fprintf(stderr, "Took %f cycles to process, or %f cycles per pixel\n",
  diff, diff / (output -> width * output -> height));

 return diffPerPixel;
}
```

Original:

```
int a = filter -> getDivisor();
int n = filter -> getSize();    
for (int plane = 0; plane < 3; plane++){
    for(int row = 1; row < (input -> height) - 1 ; row = row + 1) {
        for(int col = 1; col < (input -> width) - 1; col = col + 1) {
            int value = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    value = value + input -> color[plane][row + i - 1][col + j - 1]
                    * filter -> get(i, j);
                }
            }
            value = value / a;
            if ( value  < 0 ) { value = 0; }
            if ( value  > 255 ) { value = 255; }
            output -> color[plane][row][col] = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method only is correct if n is a multiple of 2. Otherwise you will miss one line.

ADDED:

First of all, I just realized that you forgot to initialize `val1` and `val2` which is probably the main reason for your problems.

Second, it seems to me, that your code was written specifically for filter sizes of 3:

- For smaller filters you don't access the borders at all.
- For bigger ones, you access positions outside of the picture, as e.g.
  `[row + i - 1]` becomes bigger than or equal to `input->height`.

If you only want to use filters of size 3, then I would simply unrol the inner loops completely. Otherwise check the boundaries for the row and col values.

Now, for loop unrolling, I would recommend doing a google search, as you can find many examples on how to do that properly. One can be found on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding).

In your case, the simplest solution  would be:

```
int value = 0;
int val1=0, val2=0;
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i+=2) {
        val1 = val1 + input->color[plane][row+i-1][col+j-1] * filter->get(i  ,j);
        val2 = val2 + input->color[plane][row+i  ][col+j-1] * filter->get(i+1,j);
    }
    if (n%2 !=0) {
        val1 = val1 + input->color[plane][row+n-2][col+j-1] * filter->get(n-1,j);
    }
}
value = (val1 + val2) / a;
```

In case you want to unroll the loop even more, the more generic way would be (e.g. for 4):

```
int value = 0;
int val1=0, val2=0, val3=0, val4=0;
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

    for (int i = 0; i < n-3; i+=4) {
        val1 = val1 + input->color[plane][row+i-1][col+j-1] * filter->get(i  ,j);
        val2 = val2 + input->color[plane][row+i  ][col+j-1] * filter->get(i+1,j);
        val3 = val3 + input->color[plane][row+i+1][col+j-1] * filter->get(i+2,j);
        val4 = val4 + input->color[plane][row+i+2][col+j-1] * filter->get(i+3,j);
    }
    switch (n % 4) {
        case 3: val1+=input->color[plane][row+n-4][col+j-1] * filter->get(i+n-3,j);
        case 2: val1+=input->color[plane][row+n-3][col+j-1] * filter->get(i+n-2,j);
        case 1: val1+=input->color[plane][row+n-2][col+j-1] * filter->get(i+n-1,j);
    }
    value = (val1 + val2 + val3 + val4) / a;
}
```

NOTE:
Please be aware, that depending on the size of your filter, the used compiler and compiler options and your system, the solutions above might not speed up your code but even slow it down. You should also be aware that the compiler can usually do loop unroling for you (e.g. with the [-funroll-loops](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) option in gcc) if it makes sense.

Comment: So can I do something like:     for (;i <n; i++){ val3 = val3 + input -> color[plane][row+i-1][col+j-1] * filter->get(i,j)}                       Basically compensates for the rest.

Comment: I modified my answer in order to give you a more complete answer to your question. I hope I didn't make any error with the indices.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the inner loop with:

```
int value = 0;
int val1 = 0, val2 = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { 
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i+=2) {
        val1 += input->color[plane][row+i-1][col+j-1] * filter->get(i,j);
        val2 += input->color[plane][row+i  ][col+j-1] * filter->get(i+1,j);
    } 
    if (i < n)
        val1 += input->color[plane][row+i-1][col+j-1] * filter->get(i,j);
} 
value = (val1 + val2) / a;
```